# How to check all elements of a column is in another column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Here is a small example:

```
In [1]: from pandas import DataFrame

In [2]: df = DataFrame({"x":range(10), "y":0})

In [3]: df
Out[3]:
   x  y
0  0  0
1  1  0
2  2  0
3  3  0
4  4  0
5  5  0
6  6  0
7  7  0
8  8  0
9  9  0
```

How can I check that all elements of column y is in column x?

Answer (score 2):

One liner:

```
all([i in df['x'] for i in df['y']])
```

#### Updated:

If you are after performance, you can set index on 'x' and drop the list comprehension and make it generator, it further reduces the lookup time.

```
df = df.set_index('x')

%timeit all(i in df.index for i in set(df['y']))
100000 loops, best of 3: 14.7 µs per loop
```

Or if your data will have duplicate, apart from building an index, you may also consider assign temp name like `x, y = set(df['x']), set(df['y'])` to further reduce duplicate records and have slight performance gain.

Comment: True, it just demonstrates how it can be done. Are you after performance?

Comment: I just timed it, it's about **47 µs per loop** whereas another answer takes approx. **97.4 µs per loop**

Answer (score 1):

This will get you a series where each element tells you if the corresponding element of column x is in column y:

```
in_y = df['x'].apply(lambda x : x in df['y'])
```

So then use the .all() method:

```
all_in_y = in_y.all()
```

You could obviously combine this into one line, but I figured two is better for illustrating the commands.